# spring oauth 2 authorization server app share same security context with another app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have **two authorization server application** ( **spring boot 2.0.5** ).

The two authorization server application are similaire

When a **user ask** for a **token**, spring will **register** a **session** for that specific user and give back a **token**, with that token you can access to the **resource of application 1** but you **can't access to the resource of application 2**.

My question is if there is a way to **share the same security context** in addion when you generate token from application 1 you can use to access of application 2 resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to make your applications stateless when it comes to security.

What does it mean?

Spring Security will no longer generate a session for a new logged in user. When the user logs in, you will issue him a token (e.g. JWT). Each time when the user accesses secured content, he/she will have to provide a token and your applications will verify that token with a public or private key (depending on which type of token encryption you will use -  symmetric or asymmetric). In the end, you will not need to share anything, if both of your applications have same keys to verify incoming tokens.

**Some tips:**

A token you send upon each request to access secured resources is called "access token". Make it *expirable* and make it short lived (like 15 mins). Why? This token cannot be immediately invalidated unlike session which can be simply deleted. In case if someone hijacks it, it will be still able to access secured resources.

Since your "access token" is short lived, it would be annoying for a user to logs in every 15 minutes. To prolong its life, you can have another type of token called "refresh token" that can be stored in some database. This token can be immediately invalidated by simply deleting it from the database. Therefore, if someone even hijacks it, user will be able to revoke it and the hijacker will not be able to prolong his session.

References: [Stateless authentication with JWT](https://github.com/tinmegali/Oauth2-Stateless-Authentication-with-Spring-and-JWT-Token)

Comment: @BranislavLazic    Thanks for you response , maybe i didn't explain well , i have multiple (3 instance )  of authorization server application that use access token with a Load Balancing ( Ribbo ) so when a user login to the first instance and then instance 1 will be off ribbon will switch to instance 2 at this point we don't need the client make authentication again !!

Comment: @KrDjamel Yup. I'm perfectly aware of that. By not having any state (session) in your application, you don't have to worry which one of them will be hit by load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

We are also facing similar problem.
For web pages we are using SSO which cache token in clientContext and using Authorization-server-1

For making call to API-1 we are using token generated by Authorization-server-2. In this case we have create another session bean for clientContext and that is caching token (having its own oauth2RestTemplate and clientCredientialResource)
This is two legged scenario
We doing research, how to use three legged scenario for calling web/rest service, but we were not able to do so, as access token retrieval is two step process (using authorization code) and call back will execute the whole method again and not continue from line after call to rest api